# How to create runtime version output that reflects the revision/commit of a SCM?

Tags: git, svn, versioning

Some programs print a version in the form of `x.y.z-[git commit/svn id]` (e.g. `1.3-9-gddc8d41` as returned by `git describe --tags`) for development releases. I would like to know how this is done regarding the following problems:

In order to get the version into the program to be printed at runtime (e.g. when the program is invoked with `--version`) it needs to be know at compile time. Usually one commits after testing (which implies compilation). Either

- the version printed at runtime refers to the previous commit or
- for every commit one has to do another with the identical set of files which updates the version (and then there's still a mismatch between the version printed at runtime and the revision id/commit hash in the SCM)

One could determine the revision id or the even the commit hash before the commit and write it into the version file. Is that how it's done? If yes, how specifically.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to include the actual SCM revision/commit identifier, the second way you list is how it is generally done.  The duplicate file set is referred to as a *tag* (in both [Git](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging) and [SVN](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.branchmerge.tags.html)), and has several important properties that are conventions:

- The tag is functionally identical to the copy source, though some changes are allowed to support versioning;
- It will have no more commits beyond its original creation (which is often times enforced via hooks or permissions).

This way, the code in the tag matches exactly last revision it was copied from -- except for the version information -- and the apparent "mismatch" of revision numbers is irrelevant.

The SVN team does exactly this, and [here you can see an example](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/?revision=1644006&view=revision) of them tagging 1.8.11 and setting the version information in the same commit.

Comment: I'm having trouble applying this to `git`. How to create those tags with `git`. Afaiu this is unrelated to `git`'s built-in `tag` facility as it doesn't create copies of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Abstracting @PartickQuirk's answer: One can generally achieve the output of a version reflecting the SCM commit at runtime by both

- excluding the source of the static version information (usually hardcoded in a literal in a file), e.g. by generating it from a template, and
- not managing the compilation result ("binary") producing the version output in the SCM (but the source, of course)

It's not necessary to copy any files (the SCM might do it internally, though).